# combining scala mixing,self types and cascading method fails..is possible avoid it?

Tags: scala

I've a small sample code but it fail and I can't explain the reason

```
    class ClassA(val name : String){
        def hello ={
         println ("hi "+name)
         this
     }

     def Ok = {
          println ("ok ")
          this
     }

 }

 trait TraitA {
     self : ClassA =>

     def sayHelloAgain    ={
         println ("hi again"+name)
         this
   }
  }
```

perfectly I can do

```
           val x = new ClassA("Mike") with TraitA
           x.hello.Ok
```

this works ok too

```
           val x = new ClassA("Mike") with TraitA
           x.sayHelloAgain
```

but this doesn't

```
           val x = new ClassA("Mike") with TraitA
           x.hello.Ok.sayHelloAgain
```

trying in other way this doesnt works neither

```
           class X extends ClassA("Mike") with TraitA
           val x = new x  
           x.Ok.sayHelloAgain //not works
           x.sayHelloAgain  //works!!
```

this latest example is more clear to me, when I return this from method Ok I'm returning an instance from the classA instead of class X...

is possible "fix" this code and avoiding this behaviour or the only way how can accomplish this cascade method call is using implicit conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the type returned by your methods in `ClassA` is determined locally, independently of `TraitA`, and the only type that makes sense in that context is `ClassA`. Running `$ scalac -print test.scala` shows:

```
[[syntax trees at end of                   cleanup]] // test.scala
package <empty> {
  class ClassA extends Object {
    <paramaccessor> private[this] val name: String = _;
    <stable> <accessor> <paramaccessor> def name(): String = ClassA.this.name;
    def hello(): ClassA = {
      scala.this.Predef.println("hi ".+(ClassA.this.name()));
      this
    };
    def Ok(): ClassA = {
      scala.this.Predef.println("ok ");
      this
    };
    def <init>(name: String): ClassA = {
      ClassA.this.name = name;
      ClassA.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  };
  abstract trait TraitA extends Object { self: ClassA => 
    def sayHelloAgain(): ClassA
  };
  abstract trait TraitA$class extends  { self: ClassA => 
    def sayHelloAgain($this: ClassA): ClassA = {
      scala.this.Predef.println("hi again".+($this.name()));
      $this
    };
    def /*TraitA$class*/$init$($this: ClassA): Unit = {
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

`ClassA` has no `sayHellowAgain` method, explaining the behavior you've seen. It's not a type-safe operation within Scala's type system. As you've said, using implicit conversions is one way of doing something like what you suggest. Another option is the have both the class and the trait extend an abstract trait that defines the interface you want. It's tough to say what would be best without knowing what you're really trying to accomplish. It's a bit weird to see methods that return `this` in Scala, because that implies that you're relying on side-effects.

Comment: thanks so much for your reply..I notice the reason of this behaviour when I run the latest code than I posted, but your comment " It's a bit weird to see methods that return this in Scala, because that implies that you're relying on side-effects" was the most important, I solve it using implicit and immutable data structures...